# Не могу понять причину по которой не проходят тесты

Tags: golang, юнит-тесты, test-driven-development

Собственно код на Го. Код - полностью рабочий, в нем ничего менять не надо.

```go
package main

import "fmt"

func greet(name string){
    fmt.Printf("hello, %v !\n", name)
    bye := greet2(name)
    fmt.Printf("getting ready to say bye...\n")
    bye()
}

func greet2(name string) func() {
    fmt.Printf("how are you, %v ?\n", name)
    bye := func() {
        fmt.Println("ok bye!")
    }
    return bye
}

func main()  {
    greet("Sasha")
}
```

А вот код тестов, который не проходит.

```go
package main

import "testing"

func TestGreet(t *testing.T)  {
    got := greet("Sasha") // ./scope_test.go:6:14: greet("Sasha") used as value
    want := "hello, Sasha !\nhow are you, Sasha ?\ngetting ready to say bye...\nok bye!\n"

    if got != want {
        t.Errorf("got %q want %q", got, want)
    }
}
```

Подскажите, что я делаю не так и где совершаю ошибку? Так как по правилам написания unit-тестов все должно срабатывать.

Answer (score 3):

У вас странные представления о тестах.  Функция `bye` ничего
не возвращает.  Либо собирайте строку и возвращайте её, например
с помощью `fmt.Sprintf`, либо добавляйте
`io.Writer` в качестве аргумена и используйте
`fmt.Fprintf`, либо используйте
[примеры](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/#hdr-Examples),
если уж очень хотите именно `fmt.Printf`.